# pdfrender android parcefiledescriptor from buffer byte array

Tags: android, pdfrenderer

I have a pdf into a byte array buffer.
I would like to open it with PdfRender in Android, but PdfRender accepts only in the constructor ParcelFileDescriptor.

```
 Java.IO.File f = new Java.IO.File (pdfPathfile);
 ParcelFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = ParcelFileDescriptor.Open (f, ParcelFileMode.ReadOnly);
 var mPdfRenderer = new PdfRenderer (fileDescriptor);
```

I would not want to save the buffer to a file. How can I use it directly?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem and my solution is

```
fun getFileDescriptor(byteArray: ByteArray): ParcelFileDescriptor {
    val file = File.createTempFile("temp", null)
        .also { FileOutputStream(it).write(byteArray) }

    return ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY)
}
```